# After using ${PODS_ROOT}, Still can not get the hints when import the third party library in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

Like the topic, After following the install steps, I still can not import the Alamofire library....

Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.3'
```

Already added ${PODS_ROOT} on User Header Search Path

Comment: make sure you are using workspace rather than .proj. Then build it before you code

Answer (score 0):

1. Pod Install to generate the workspace file and alert if any error.
2. Run the .xcworkspace instead of running the original .xcodeproj
3. Import Alamofire inside your project and rebuild the project.